# CLI has stopped working, I tried all previous answers

Tags: php, windows, wamp, command-line-interface, wampserver

I installed the latest version of wampserver 3.0.6 and when I enter `php -v` in the command line, a window appears that says

> "CLI has stopped working. A problem caused the program to stop working correctly. Windows will close the problem and notify you if a solution is available."

This happens on both php 5.0.25 and 7.0.10

Because of this I cannot install Composer so I can't get any coding done.

I have searched Stack Overflow and read the questions of other people having the same problem, but none of the answers there helped me. I run Windows 8.1 64 bit.

This happens on wampserver, mampserver, xampp and Uniform Server.

```
Faulting application name: php.exe, version: 5.6.25.0, time stamp: 0x57b60174
Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 6.3.9600.18438, time stamp: 0x57ae642e
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0000000000030c57
Faulting process ID: 0x2e70
Faulting application start time: 0x01d2aa27475e178b
Faulting application path: C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.6.25\php.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
Report ID: 870dbe02-161a-11e7-8263-38b1dbf6d8ea
Faulting package full name:
Faulting package-relative application ID:

Faulting application name: php-win.exe, version: 5.6.25.0, time stamp: 0x57b60195
Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 6.3.9600.18438, time stamp: 0x57ae642e
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0000000000030c57
Faulting process ID: 0x2f1c
Faulting application start time: 0x01d2aa0cab8c6362
Faulting application path: c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.6.25\php-win.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
Report ID: f3184580-15ff-11e7-8263-38b1dbf6d8ea
Faulting package full name:

Faulting application name: php.exe, version: 7.1.1.0, time stamp: 0x587fb9fe
Faulting module name: unknown, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x00000000
Exception code: 0xc00000fd
Fault offset: 0xffe22560
Faulting process ID: 0x2784
Faulting application start time: 0x01d2ef5b083f63c5
Faulting application path: C:\Users\user\Documents\UniformServer\core\php71\php.exe
Faulting module path: unknown
Report ID: a84b481c-5b4e-11e7-82a8-38b1dbf6d8ea
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID: 

Faulting application name: php.exe, version: 5.6.30.0, time stamp: 0x5880378d
Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 6.3.9600.18696, time stamp: 0x5915ecd6
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x00040f17
Faulting process ID: 0x15c8
Faulting application start time: 0x01d2ef52226ae6a9
Faulting application path: C:\xampp\php\php.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
Report ID: 609ab573-5b45-11e7-82a8-38b1dbf6d8ea
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID: 

Faulting application name: php.exe, version: 5.6.30.0, time stamp: 0x5880378d
Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 6.3.9600.18696, time stamp: 0x5915ecd6
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x00040f17
Faulting process ID: 0x1ac4
Faulting application start time: 0x01d2ef5183067933
Faulting application path: C:\xampp\php\php.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
Report ID: cc689e33-5b44-11e7-82a8-38b1dbf6d8ea
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

Comment: I think most people have migrated to xampp https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html

Comment: Sounds like an issue on the application level. I would contact their support or just use another application such as https://www.mamp.info/en/downloads/

Comment: wampserver forum couldn't help me and I have the same problem with mamp for windows and mamp didn't reply to my support email. It works in xampp, but how do I make it work in wampserver, considering wampserver supports multiple versions of php?

Comment: This happens on wampserver, mampserver, xampp and Uniform Server.